# <!--[if IE]> Not working even though I'm sure I wrote it in correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I made these one for IE and one not for IE.  The one for not IE shows in IE and for those that aren't IE. Does the new IE not support this or is my IE just messed up?  I'm pretty sure I wrote these in correctly because even the resources for the book I'm reading doesn't work.  Or is it that the author of this book I are missing something.

This is my work:

```
For IE: <!--[if IE]><div class="ieFlow"><h1>Your Board</h1></div><![endif]-->
For not IE <!--[if !IE]--><div class="Flow"><h1>Your Board</h1></div><!--[endif]-->
```

This is the book's work:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <h1>You're using IE</h1>
<![endif]-->
```

Neither work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [IE10 conditional comments are not supported by standards mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: D: Is there any other way to do something like that

Comment: Check my comment, you can do it with javascript by detecting the browser type and version

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but feature detection is the preferred way to detect a browsers capabilities and adjust functionality.

Comment: +1, @dc5. You'd better have a *damn* good reason for using browser hacks; they're brittle and unreliable. [0](http://www.sitepoint.com/why-browser-sniffing-stinks/), [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing#Issues_and_standards)

Comment: Well my problem was that my text appeared hellishly large in IE so I was going to make a separate text size for it.  So feature detection I don't think will work because they both have the features to display text.

Comment: @Zachooz there might be a different problem there.  Maybe worth posting that as a question on SO?

Comment: I looked over the list of ways to detect if its IE or not in the new version.  This would make it so I would have to have 3 detections.  One for old IE one for New IE and one for others.  I came to the conclusion that I could live with it being twice the size in IE because the font that's being doubled is a header anyway and all I'd have to do is not make the others a bit smaller than normal.  IE is a pain in the but though.  Why does it always have to be the renegade.

Answer (score 0):

Please click on following links to read about conditional stylesheet

1. [CSS TRICK](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)
2. [Conditional Stylesheet for IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

OR

you can use this javascript file, CSS Browser Selector: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

it allows you to target specific browsers by using class names:

```
 .ie .example {
      background-color: yellow
    }
    .ie7 .example {
      background-color: orange
    }
    .gecko .example {
      background-color: gray
    }
    .win.gecko .example {
      background-color: red
    }
    .linux.gecko .example {
      background-color: pink
    }
    .opera .example {
      background-color: green
    }
    .konqueror .example {
      background-color: blue
    }
    .webkit .example {
      background-color: black
    }
```

Comment: Which one is not working, javascript solution?

Comment: Oh wait I have to get their javascript